# Django checkout model

Tags: django, django-models, python-2.7

What is the best way to create a checkout system with Django that keeps track of the checkout / checkin history?

My models for `inventory/models.py`

```
from django.db import models

class Groups(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Inventory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    serial = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    barcode = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    active = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="Active (can be checked out if not out for repair)",blank=True,default=True)
    repair = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="Out for repair?",blank=True)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Groups)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

I am thinking I will need another model that will store the checkout / in information? I am guessing I will need to only obtain the last one so that I know if it is checked in or out? I want to keep a history of the items so that I can create a report with it.

How would I go about making it so I have a history of the items and if the items can be checked in or out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it isn't totally clear from your question what a checkout/checkin is, but my guess is you want something like

```
class Checkout(models.Model)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Inventory)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    checked_out = models.DateTimeField()
    checked_in = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    ...
```

You would then create one of these objects each time an item was checked out, and then update it to set the checkin date when it was checked back in.

To find the current checkout (or determine if something is not checked out) you could do a query like:

```
try:
    checkout = Checkout.objects.get(item=my_item, checked_in=None)
except Checkout.DoesNotExist:
    #item isn't checked out
    checkout = None
```

Comment: Checkout would be a new app?

Comment: Checkout would be another model in `inventory/models.py`.  A new app would probably be overkill.